# how to change active character in Dungeon Siege 3?

Tags: pc, dungeon-siege-3

can i change the first character when playing in local co-op mode on pc ?

just the second player can change his character when he leaves the game and joins again, then he can choose who he wants to be.

but me as the first player, i cannot change the character.

even in single player mode i am always the one i chose at the start and can just change the second one who accompanies me.

is there a way to change my active character in single player mode, so i could change it and then let the second player join and choose another one ?

i don't want to be the mage anymore and want to play the montbarron because he has way more points right now and is better in direct contact fight. second player plays the fire girl and wants to stay with it.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I can tell there is no way to change the active character in co-op or single player mode.

The reason for this is that each character initiates a different perspective on the story. The first player's character is in charge of the story's events. Changing the character would compromise the background information and change a lot of the dialogue.

Short of starting a new game, I don't believe there is anything else you can do.